# How to reduce the startup time for MySQL 5.7 with many databases?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 5.7.24 running on a Windows VM. It has a few thousand databases (7000). I understand this is not the recommended set up for MySQL but some business requirements have necessitated this multi-tenant db structure and I cannot change that unfortunately.

The server works fine when it is running but the startup time can get pretty long, almost 20-30 mins after a clean shutdown of the MySQL service and 1+ hours after a restart of the Windows VM.

Is there any way to reduce the startup time?

In my configuration, I observed that innodb_file_per_table = ON (which is the default for MySQL 5.7 I believe) and so I think that at startup it is scanning every .ibd file.

Would changing innodb_file_per_table = OFF and then altering each table to get rid of the .ibd files be a viable option. One thing to note is that in general, every database size is pretty small and even with 7000 databases, the total size of the data is about 60gb only. So to my understanding, innodb_file_per_table = ON is more beneficial when there are single tables that can get pretty large which is not the case for my server.

**Question:** Is my logic reasonable and could this innodb_file_per_table be the reason for the slow startup? Or is there some other config variable that I can change so that each .ibd file is not scanned before the server starts accepting connections.

Any help to guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't, repeat don't, try turning off `innodb_file_per_table` for that setup. Or it will try to cram thousands of tables into a few files. That will be unpleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

I was working on a system with the same problem as yours. In our case, we had about 1500 schemas per MySQL instance, and a little over 100 tables per schema. So it was about 160,000+ tables per instance. It caused lots of problems trying to use `innodb_file_per_table`, because the mysqld process couldn't work with that many open file descriptors efficiently. The only way to make the system work was to abandon file-per-table, and move all the tables into the central tablespace.

But that causes a different problem. Tablespaces never shrink, they only grow. The only way to shrink a tablespace is to move the tables to another tablespace, and drop the big one.

One day one of the developers added some code that used a table like a log, inserting a vast number of rows very rapidly. I got him to stop logging that data, but by then it was too late. MySQL's central tablespace had expanded to 95% of the size of the database storage, leaving too little space for binlogs and other files. And I could never shrink it without incurring downtime for our business.

I asked him, "Why were you writing to that table so much? What are you doing with the data you're storing?" He shrugged and said casually, "I dunno, I thought the data might be interesting sometime, but I had no specific use for them." I felt like strangling him.

The point of this story is that one naïve developer can cause a lot of inconvenience if you disable `innodb_file_per_table`.

When MySQL 8.0 was being planned, the MySQL Product Manager solicited ideas for scalability criteria. I told him about the need to support instances with a lot of tables, like 160k or more. MySQL 8.0 included an all-new implementation of internal code for handling metadata about tables, and he asked the engineers to test the scalability with up to 1 million tables (with file-per-table enabled).

So the best solution to your problem is not to turn off `innodb_file_per_table`. That will just lead to another kind of crisis. The best solution is to upgrade to 8.0.

---

Re your comment:

As far as I know, InnoDB does not open tables at startup time. It opens tables when they are first queried.

Make sure you have `table_open_cache` and `innodb_open_files` tuned for your scale. Here is some reading:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-cache.html
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/11/18/how-innodb_open_files-affects-performance/
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/11/28/what-happens-if-you-set-innodb_open_files-higher-than-open_files_limit/
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/10/01/one-million-tables-mysql-8-0/

I hope you are using an SSD for storage, not a spinning disk. This makes a huge difference when doing a lot of small I/O operations. SSD storage devices have been a standard recommendation for database servers for about 10 years.

Also this probably doesn't help you but I gave up on using Windows around 2007. Not as a server nor a desktop.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your detailed answer. Will check if we are able to upgrade to 8.0 as I do understand that might be the best solution. In the interim, while we figure out the logistics of that migration, is there anything you know could help specifically with the startup time issue? Is there any configuration option to skip reading each ibd file on startup even after a clean shutdown?

Comment: Thanks Bill, my apologies for the late reply - I missed your edit to your answer as it did not trigger a notification to me. I have been trying the different config options suggested by you but am unable to still improve the startup time. InnoDB does not open tables at startup times, but I believe it scans the first page of every .idb file at startup and that is what seems to be taking super long. Do you know if there is any way to skip that? Many thanks again.

Comment: One way might be to reduce the number of .idb files by putting multiple tables together into general tablespaces. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html This has its own tradeoffs of course.

Comment: Okay will check that out. Thank you

Comment: Bill, do you think migrating lots of tables to a smaller number of [general tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html) would help this person's unfortunate situation? It would reduce the open file count.

Comment: @O.Jones, General Tablespaces would reduce the number of open files, but they would take a lot more deliberate care to avoid expanding the tablespaces. They never shrink, even if you OPTIMIZE TABLE. This is just like the system tablespace (and any tablespace, for that matter). To recover storage space, you'd have to move _all_ the tables to a new general tablespace, and then drop the old one. So you'd temporarily need double the storage space, because the old general tablespace still does not shrink as you remove tables from it.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL does not support a huge database size efficiently

Comment: The answer it's not related to the question itself. The question is related to many databases number and the answer says about huge size of database. We can have many small databases, the question would still valid and the answer wouldn't